# What is the namespace while creating a MS Access database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am exporting a gridview to MS Access but I am facing some problems.

What namespace I should be using while creating a MS access database in C#?

Comment: `using System.Data.OleDb;`

Answer (score 2):

For playing with Microsoft office realated document like MS-Access or MS-Excel you need to add

```
using System.Data.OleDb
```

Answer (score 2):

write some code

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
```

then right click on the class name (e.g. OleDbConnection) and select resolve or you can use shortcut `ctrl + .`

In this specific case you need to add

```
using System.Data.OleDb
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add reference to this namespace in your project `System.Data.OleDb`

and then use it on you file like this

```
using System.Data.OleDb
```

Comment: Yes But I am using: using ADOX; and using ADODB;

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Data.OleDb` namespace needs to be added in your c# file. You can refer the below detailed sample which help you to learn more about MS Access data storage and retrieval through `C#`.

[Link to Refer](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/94800/insertingdeletingupdating-and-editing-records-to-a-ms-access-database)

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2 namespace

1. using ADOX;
2. Using ADODB;

Answer (score 0):

yes i am using namespace 
using System.Data.OLEDB; with 2 namespace 
using ADOX;
using ADODB; with this code

```
    ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
    ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();

    //Create the table and it's fields. 
    table.Name = "Table1";
    table.Columns.Append("PartNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 6); // text[6]
    table.Columns.Append("AnInteger", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 10); // Integer 
    try
    {
        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=d:/m2.accdb;" + "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
        cat.Tables.Append(table);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;" + "Data Source=d:/m2.accdb");
       conn.Open();

             OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
             cmd.Connection = conn;

             cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1([PartNumber],[AnInteger]) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName)";

             cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "neha";

             cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 20;

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();                                 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    cat = null;
```